# file is not created in system32 folder using fopen function

Tags: windows, service, fopen

Iam using c language. My application is a server application in windows. i have used "GetCurrentDirectory" MSDN dunction to get the current directory. The output is "C:\Windows\system32". Now i have used "CreateDirectory" function to create directory under "C:\Windows\system32". The directory is successfully created. Now i have used "fopen" function in "w" mode, to create the file in "C:\Windows\System32\MILI_files\" directory. But fopen function returned NULL with strerror(errno) returning as "No such file or directory". 
Iam unable to find what is causing fopen function return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Really not positive about it, but one thing comes to my mind.

Try running your app as admin, it is highly possible your app does not have permissions to write into system32 folder or that file can't even be created there.

If I go to system32 I can't even create a file there, the only action windows menu is offering is new folder and I can delete folders or files only if I accept the windows UAC prompt

EDIT: To test your application works and problem is in inability to create new file in sys32, try creating file somewhere like on your desktop to see if function works there

Comment: But if i manually add the file (right click and add new document). Then the file is getting created. As suggested above i have logged in as Administrator in my windows setup but still not able to create file with fopen function.

Comment: You are logged in as user, but applications aren't being run with admin privileges.

Try doing this:

Open User Account Control Settings by clicking the Start button , and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type uac, and then click Change User Account Control settings.
Turn off UAC, move the slider to the Never notify position, and then click OK.

Try your application to see if it works and turn UAC back to where it was after it. If your application works with UAC off it means you need to run your application as admin by right clicking on it and selecting "Run as administrator"